# Does anyone know the amount of resources that a C program that handles 1080 x 1920 pixel images may require?

Tags: c, iot, hardware

I am developing a project that consists of extracting text from images and then placing them in a .txt file and later converting that .txt into an mp3 that will be played by some speakers. My problem is that I do not know what type of microcontroller will be able to carry out all these tasks taking into account that I want it to be as economical as possible.

Comment: This is talking about text files, sound, and graphics *all at once*. Can you try and focus on one particular thing?

Comment: The data size of uncompressed 1080x1920 pixel image is about 260KB (1bit / pixel), 2MB (8bit / pixel), 6MB (24bit / pixel), or 8MB (32bit / pixel). The required resource will depend on the process you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, you should start with your calculator and punch in the numbers to see what you get.

For example, a 1920 x 1080 pixel image with 1 bit per pixel is ~253KB of data.

If you're handling large image files, a microcontroller isn't going to cut it. Most microcontrollers have less than 1MB of memory total, if that. The [Raspberry Pi Pico](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/rp2040/getting-started/#board-specifications) for example has 264KB of memory, a fairly generous amount, and that can barely hold a bitmap image that size.

You need a more robust processor. A Raspberry Pi has 2GB+ of memory and can handle images that scale at 24-bit color depth. 1920 x 1080 x 3 bytes per pixel is about 5.9MB of data. Totally manageable on a system with >32MB of memory.

Remember, microcontrollers excel at performing simple tasks like driving a keyboard, servo motors, communicating with sensors and such, and are really bad at doing intensive processing. The Pico's CPU runs at 133MHz, that's it. There's only so much you can do with a few watts of power!

You'll need a full CPU to do image processing, or even better, leverage the GPU elements on a system like the Pi to do that more efficiently, something no microcontroller is ever going to include.

Comment: In the hypothetical case that I have to mass produce this project, surely I could not use a Raspberry because it would be very expensive. What could be done in that case?

Comment: Define "very expensive". What price parameters are you working with here? Remember the Pi Zero is like $6 and cheaper in bulk. It's also just an example of using an SOC instead of a microcontroller. You can buy equivalent chips wholesale and make your own boards.

Comment: Please could you clarify what you mean by wholesale chips?

Comment: It helps if you can define your objectives better. Is this a one-off thing? Is this a product you're developing for mass-market? Do you have any hardware engineering experience? Are you willing to learn? Can you embed a product like the Pi Zero? You can source CPUs wholesale and assemble your own boards *if* you are willing to put in the time to learn, but that's a lot more work than just buying an existing solution like the Zero.

Comment: I am very willing to learn. This will not be a project presented in physical form, but my teacher asked me to propose a project and define costs and what electronic materials I will need. I want it to be theoretically a project that is implemented en masse, that is why I seek to reduce costs a lot.

Comment: *Theoretically* you can purchase an ARM SOC from a variety of vendors (e.g. DigiKey) and make your own board using open-source software like KiCAD. You can cost out those parts, including the boards, using various examples of Zero-like projects, or just use the Zero if you can't beat the price by much. The wholesale cost of an ARM CPU can be as little as $1 depending on the required capabilities and supplier. Some vendors will custom-build simple boards with a minimum quantity order, usually 1000 to 10,000 units.

Comment: Thank you very much for having resolved many of my doubts, I am very grateful.

Comment: One place to look around is shops like AliExpress to see what vendors there are, and what capabilities they have. Many advertise custom engineering services. You could ask a few for a quote, which they will gladly provide, if you know your *specific* requirements.

Answer (score 1):

For this type of task, I would recommend starting with something over-powered. You might be able to fit it into a small low-power microcontroller, but it likely won't be worth the effort. Try something on the order of the various Raspberry Pi MCUs.